# How does all services in microservice architecture (token based) know that the user has logged out?

Tags: jwt, microservices, token, aws-api-gateway, gateway

When a user logs out (sign out) of the application, how does the gateway communicate to all services that the user has logged out?

In other words, what happens when a user logs out in microservice architecture application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generic question, I will give my personal thoughts.

Let's take a Single page application, talking to bunch of Microservices and secured by a Gateway that validates the token.

When user logs in, token given by auth server is stored within browser storage(ex: localstorage).

When user log out, no communication is sent to Gateway or auth server, tokens will simply be deleted from browser storage.

So, if someone gets hold of access tokens, they can be used to call services as long as access tokens doesn't expire.

This is typically why there are two tokens given by auth server, an access token and a refresh token. Access token which is used to secure apis expires pretty quickly and a refresh token which has much longer expiry time can be used to get new access token.

Comment: Ahh, already an answer. Anyways, I didn't know about refresh tokens. Thanks, a vote from me.

Comment: got it now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

As you've included the *JWT* tag, so I'm trying to give the response by considering that only. The JWT token is a self-sufficient encoded token that contained certain attributes including an expiration period. The sole purpose is to provide stateless authentication. Authentication service usually returns two token, `access_token` and `refresh_token`. Client store both of them in some storage on their end. Access token usually issued for a very short span of time and so the client can use the refresh_token in order to get a new access_token on the expiration of the latter. One can access the services until refresh_token get expired. After that client has to go through the authentication process to get new tokens. In case when user logout from the system client should remove both of the tokens from its storage. Because as there is no state maintain in the case of JWT, the server can still accept the old token until they're not expired.

Validation of token for expiration and integrity should be done at the gateway level.

One can avoid the use of the token for service to service communications as those are internal services and running in a private network although one can do the same validation at this level too.

So in case of user sign out, the user's auth token should be removed from the client-side and the gateway should not communicate to other services. There are other special cases where token revoke is a particular case that could be handled by taking the help of distributed cached store in scaleable authentication systems.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense to me now!

Answer (score -1):

A token-based service can generally infer the following from a token -

- Who made a request?
- Upto what time this token is considered valid?
- Which actions are allowed when using this token?

A token based service just accepts or rejects a request depending on provided token, regardless of whether it is a user or a machine making the request. A logged-in user is just someone who can perform actions which this user is authorized to do. A token is a limited representation of such a user.

My point being, it is the application telling the user that they are logged in (have a token it can still use), or logged out (no token yet, or expired). Such a token is obtained by authenticating to the service using ones username and password.

Answer is based on my knowledge, so everyone, please do point out mistakes if any. I don't know in detail about aws api gateway stuff, so maybe someone else can brief you on it in case it works differently.